# printing isoscele triangle of numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

We easily produce a triangle of numbers as below:

```
1
22
333, etc...
```

What I'm looking for is the way to get the answer as:

```
    1
   22 
  333 ( each number at the center of the following, 1 between 22,etc.)
```

I can do it with stars `'*'` with this code:

```
n=int(input("give the number of star's lines:")
for i in range(n):
   T=' '*(n-i-1) + 'x'*(2*i+1)
   print(T)
```

Must I use the `def` function or others?

Thank you

Comment: Theres not enough information for your question to make sense.

Comment: Why cant you just replace `'x'` with `str(i+1)`?

Comment: @Nick A 
Thank you very much, you show me the path to understand my little problem.

Comment: And thanks a lot to Arya McCarthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.rjust()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rjust) to justify your numbers:

```
n = int(input("give the number lines: "))  # obviously, you should check for non-int inputs
for i in range(1, n + 1):  # loop our number of lines, starting from 1
    print((str(i)*i).rjust(n))  # multiply string repr. of 'i' by itself and 'rjust' it
```

Which can give you something like:

```
give the number lines: 5
    1
   22
  333
 4444
55555
```

You can increase the number used for [`str.rjust()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rjust) to give it more offset from the left side.

Comment: Another useful way that you learn me today, thank you.very much.